# Build Nested Dictionary at run time in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to build dynamic dictionary in python like this,,

```
users = {log_id : { "message_id" : "1", "sent_to" : "taqi.official@outlook.com" , "unique_arguments" : "03455097679"},
     log_id : { "message_id" : "1", "sent_to" : "taqi.hass@cogilent.com" , "unique_arguments" : "03455097679" },
     log_id : { "message_id" : "2 Turab", "sent_to" : "taqi.official@gmailllllll.com" , "unique_arguments" : "4534534535" }}
```

I have write this code but it is not building as i desired;

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select log_id, message_id, sent_to, unique_arguments from sendmessage_log_messages where log_status = 'Queue'")
rows = cur.fetchall()
count = 0
for row in rows:
    temp['message_id'] = row[1]
    temp['sent_to'] = str(row[2])
    temp['unique_arguments'] = row[3]
    log_dictionary[row[0]] = temp

print log_dictionary
```

It produces the this output,

```
{1: {'unique_arguments': 'log_8_taqi.official@gmailllllll.com', 'message_id': 8, 'sent_to': 'taqi.official@gmailllllll.com'}, 
2: {'unique_arguments': 'log_8_taqi.official@gmailllllll.com', 'message_id': 8, 'sent_to': 'taqi.official@gmailllllll.com'}, 
3: {'unique_arguments': 'log_8_taqi.official@gmailllllll.com', 'message_id': 8, 'sent_to': 'taqi.official@gmailllllll.com'}, 
4: {'unique_arguments': 'log_8_taqi.official@gmailllllll.com', 'message_id': 8, 'sent_to': 'taqi.official@gmailllllll.com'}}
```

Comment: Move the **missing** `temp = {}` declaration inside of the loop.

Comment: can you print the o/p properly again.I am not getting it

Comment: It seems to me you are getting the output right. What is the problem there? You want the output to be in that particular order?

Comment: @thiruvenkadam see that i am getting the same row again and again note the unique_arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Since no answer is given here, I am just giving the explanation here.

Here, you are replacing the temp dictionary again and again. When you do log_dictionary[row[0]] = temp, this just points to the existing temp dictionary. Thus whenever you change any value in the temp dictionary and you read the log_dictionary, this will always give you the updated temp dictionary only.

Try this:

```
for row in rows:
    temp['message_id'] = row[1]
    temp['sent_to'] = str(row[2])
    temp['unique_arguments'] = row[3]
    log_dictionary[row[0]] = temp
print log_dictionary
temp['message_id'] = 0
temp['send_to'] = 'stackoverflow'
temp['unique_arguments'] = None
print log_dictionary
```

This will give you the updated temp dictionary values as it is just referenced with the log_dictionary. As Ashwini Chaudhary mentioned in your comment, if you initialize a temp dictionary within the for loop before referencing it to log_dictionary, you will get the desired values. (eg)

```
for row in rows:
    temp = {}
    temp['message_id'] = row[1]
    temp['sent_to'] = str(row[2])
    temp['unique_arguments'] = row[3]
    log_dictionary[row[0]] = temp
```